# How can I Pause one tab from another tab in c# MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I need to create an application where the students are not allowed to open more than one learn tab. If the open the new tab the previous tab should be paused.

My code is:-

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(long sessionId)
        {
            var sessionIdCookies = this.Request.Cookies["sessionId"];
            var userCookies = this.Request.Cookies["userCookies"];

            if (userCookies == this.Request.Cookies[".AspNetCore.Identity.Application"] && sessionIdCookies != sessionId.ToString())
            {
                // goes here
               await PostPause(long.Parse(sessionIdCookies));
            }
            this.Response.Cookies.Append("userCookies", this.Request.Coo
//Rest of the code goes here
```

here I have used sessionId to track the page. Everything works fine here the previous tab get paused in the database but the thing is I need to refresh or reload the page manually to see the pause page. How Can I do this with in the code i.e. reload the previous tab when new tab opens.

Comment: Do you mean you want to reload the previous page if the new tag has opened? If this is your requirement, I suggest you could try to use Signalr to achieve your requirement.  By using signalr you could check each tab's status at real time. If the staus not match in the database or else. You could call the client side js codes at server-side to disable the previous tab. More details about how to use signlar you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-5.0).